# ternary operator compile error when using gcc but no issue using g++

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, gnu

I have been getting compile issues compiling this code using `gcc` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /*srand, rand*/
#include <time.h> /*time*/
#include <math.h> /*sqrt*/

int abs(int x) {
 return( (x>0) ? x : int(-x));
};
int max(int x, int y) {
 return( (x>y) ? x : y);
};
int min(int x, int y) {
 return( (x>y) ? y : x);
};
```

with this compile instruction : `gcc sqrtsumofsquares.c -o test`

The resulting error I get is this :

```
sqrtsumofsquares.c: In function 'abs':
sqrtsumofsquares.c:7:22: error: expected expression before 'int'
```

However when I compile the same code with `g++ sqrtsumofsquares.c -o test`

The code compile with no issue.

The code itself and the use of ternary operator seems to be syntactically correct

What modifications can I do to compile this code on `gcc` ? As I have to use `gcc` and not `g++`

Comment: `int(-x)` is a functional cast introduced in C++, but not valid in C. The issue isn't with the ternary operator, it's with the functional cast.

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert `-x` to `int` in the first place? It's already `int`.

Comment: Not related to the question, but function bodies do not need a `;` after the closing `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(-x)` is valid syntax in C++, but not valid syntax in C. I think you just meant to write `-x`.

`gcc` compiles C code, and `g++` compiles C++ code.

In C++ `int(something)` casts a value to `int`, the same as `(int)something`